# code review easy box and form code html5 css3

Tags: html, css, optimization

I have coded a small form, it is part of a bigger webpage and I am taking small steps, according to specification.

I am curious if I could have done it better in some way. If I could streamlined the code or used some other command or syntax that is better?

Perhaps there are some redundancies?

Also is there a good way to move the Send button so it is centered in the middle and is there a way to move it closed to the bottom without too much hassle? Or to move the placeholder text close to the left?

I will enclose a link to a pen and you can check out the code there.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pYNPrw

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="#">

    <h2>xyz xyz</h2>
    <div class="input-wrapper">
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name...." id="name">
    </div>

    <div class="input-wrapper">
      <label for="email">Epost:</label>
      <input type="text" name="Epost" placeholder="Epost...." id="epost">
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Senden</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please note that whoever downvoted had valid reasons because opinion based questions are not entertained here. But I have upvoted your answer again for your efforts and don't want you to feel discouraged here from asking/answering questions. Please read this and you will understand why you may get downvoted for questions like these - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201994/is-there-a-place-to-ask-opinion-based-questions

Comment: @Pankaj You are doing a disservice to later visitors by upvoting to counter a downvote. Your votes are yours to use as you see fit, but generally, upvoting should be reserved for those worthy of an upvote (useful, shows research, etc.) rather than merely to counter other votes.

Comment: @Amanda downvotes have nothing to do with *you*. It is an indication of the usefulness of *the question*, for others to use.

Comment: Note that if this is code you've written, and you want a review of all of the code, you may find it better placed on [codereview.se], but please read [their help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) about what's on topic there.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your code by adding margin property to adjust position of the button and commenting transform property. but if you could use a style library like bootstrap or material design you can sort out a form way more faster

```css
h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 margin-bottom: 2.3rem;
}

form {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .5rem;
  height: 205px;
  width: 168px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.input-wrapper {
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

label {
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
 font-family: Sans-Serif;
font-size: 14px;
}

input {
  width: 90px;
  padding: .5rem;
  height: 3px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: left;
}

button {      
  padding: .5rem;
  display: block;
  width: 55%; 
  background: lightgrey;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: inherit;
  /* transform: translate(50%, 50%); */
  margin: 60px auto;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="#">

    <h2>xyz xyz</h2>
    <div class="input-wrapper">
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name...." id="name">
    </div>

    <div class="input-wrapper">
      <label for="email">Epost:</label>
      <input type="text" name="Epost" placeholder="Epost...." id="epost">
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Senden</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```